# Error in Advanced C assignment

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, scanf

Having trouble with my assignment. I have my program to where it will run, but I'm having issues getting it to work properly. I'm supposed to and define a structure type 'auto_t' and include components for the make, model, manufacture and purchase dates, fuel cap, fuel level, and odometer. Each divided into I/O functions (scan_auto, scan_date, scan_tank, print_auto, print_date, print_tank) and also write a driver function to repeatedly fill and display an auto structure variable until EOF is encounter in the input file. Example data set is: Mercury Sable  1 18 2001 5 30 1991 16 12.5 99892

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
char make[15];
char model[30];

int mmon;
int mday;
int myear;

int pmon;
int pday;
int pyear;

float fuelcap;
float fuellevel;

float odometer;
} auto_t;
```

/* Takes in make and model */

```
int scan_auto(auto_t *vehicle) {
return scanf("%s %s", vehicle->make, vehicle->model);
}
```

/* Takes in manufacture and purchase dates */

```
int scan_date(auto_t *date) {
return scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d"
        , &date->mmon
        , &date->mday
        , &date->myear
        , &date->pmon
        , &date->pday
        , &date->pyear);            
}
```

/* Takes in fuel and odometer info */

```
int scan_tank(auto_t *tank) {
return scanf("%f %f %f"
        , &tank->fuelcap
        , &tank->fuellevel
        , &tank->odometer);

void print_auto(auto_t vehicle) {
printf("%s %s \n"
    , vehicle.make
    , vehicle.model);
}

void print_date(auto_t date) {
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d \n"
    , date.mmon
    , date.mday
    , date.myear
    , date.pmon
    , date.pday
    , date.pyear);
}

void print_tank(auto_t tank) {
printf("%f %f %f \n"
    , tank.fuelcap
    , tank.fuellevel
    , tank.odometer);
}
```

/* Driver */

```
int main(void) {
auto_t vehicle, date, tank;

while(1) {
    printf("Please enter the make, then model of the car: ");
    scan_auto(&vehicle);
        if(scan_auto(&vehicle) == EOF){
            break;
        }
    printf("Please enter the manufacture and purchase dates (ex. 1 18 2001): ");        
    scan_date(&date);
        if(scan_date(&date) == EOF){
            break;
        }
    printf("Please enter the fuel cap, current fuel level (in gallons), and the current      odometer reading: ");
    scan_tank(&tank);
        if(scan_tank(&tank) == EOF){
            break;
        }
/* Prints all of the cars information */    
    print_auto(vehicle);
    print_date(date);
    print_tank(tank);

}
return 0;       
}
```

My issues are that when I run the program the data in not taken in properly by the scanf function and the scan_tank is being skipped. The print functions at the end also seem to be printing the wrong data (the make and model are not even shown) and I'm not sure if it's something wrong with the scan or print functions I'm using. Also I can't seem to get the programs loop to end and the program keeps going until I close it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. And I'm coding in C and using TextWrangler.

Comment: Your sample data looks like it has the odometer as the first number, but the scan looks at it together with the fuel levels -- you need to read the fields in the right order...

Comment: Unrelated: I would guess the odometer date info would be considerably more useful scanned into the members of the passed-in auto rather than to a stack of local variables that are subsequently lost on function-return. Likewise with `scan_auto`. And you're doubling all your scan calls How many times do you need to call `scan_date` per auto anyway (as an example).

Comment: Yeah the odometer info is something I'd actually put into the proper order, being at the end like I have in my code. However, I can't even put in the odometer data as the whole scan_tank data is skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

There are other issues in the code:

1. Change the `scanf` is not for performance, `date->&pyear` is totally
   **wrong** since `pyear` is a member of `date`, whereever if you wanted access `pyear`, use  `data->pyear` . `&date->pyear` means
   `&(date->pyear)` because the priority `->` is higher than `&`.
2. The function `scan_auto`, `scan_date` and `scan_tank` are invoked
   twice, I know I didn't want that, so

`//scan_auto(&vehicle);
if(scan_auto(&vehicle) == EOF)` 
The line in `if` statement will be executed as well, so comment the above one, so are other "scan" function.
EDITED 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
char make[15];
char model[30];

int mmon;
int mday;
int myear;

int pmon;
int pday;
int pyear;

float fuelcap;
float fuellevel;

float odometer;
} auto_t;

int scan_auto(auto_t *vehicle) {
return scanf("%s %s", vehicle->make, vehicle->model);
}

int scan_date(auto_t *date) {
return scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d"
        , &date->mmon
        , &date->mday
        , &date->myear
        , &date->pmon
        , &date->pday
        , &date->pyear);
}
int scan_tank(auto_t *tank) {
return scanf("%f %f %f"
        , &tank->fuelcap
        , &tank->fuellevel
        , &tank->odometer);
}
void print_auto(auto_t vehicle) {
printf("%s %s \n"
    , vehicle.make
    , vehicle.model);
}
void print_date(auto_t date) {
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d \n"
    , date.mmon
    , date.mday
    , date.myear
    , date.pmon
    , date.pday
    , date.pyear);
}

void print_tank(auto_t tank) {
printf("%f %f %f \n"
    , tank.fuelcap
    , tank.fuellevel
    , tank.odometer);
}
int main()
{
auto_t vehicle;
auto_t date;
auto_t tank;
while(1) {
    printf("Please enter the make, then model of the car: \n");
    //scan_auto(&vehicle);
    if(scan_auto(&vehicle) == EOF){
        break;
    }
    printf("Please enter the manufacture and purchase dates (ex. 1 18 2001): \n");
    //scan_date(&date);
        if(scan_date(&date) == EOF){
            break;
        }
    printf("Please enter the fuel cap, current fuel level (in gallons), and the current      odometer reading: \n");
    //scan_tank(&tank);
        if(scan_tank(&tank) == EOF){
            break;
        }
    print_auto(vehicle);
    print_date(date);
    print_tank(tank);

    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, implemented the changes and it is certainly more effective than the way I did the first time. I'm still having my main problem though. Whenever the program runs it will as for the make and model like it's supposed to, however, it doesn't move on to the next printf after I type the answer, so the scanf receives more data than it should and the scan_tank function is being skipped all together. Lastly the final printf function isn't printing the proper data onto the screen, leaving the make and model completely out of the data set.

Comment: Commented out the scan function like you suggested and nothings changed, but it still works. Can't use the `date->pyear` as it causes this to pop up:  **warning: 
      format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]**

Comment: Thanks that solved my original problem. So in hindsight, having **void** in **int main(void) {** didn't make sense, but what is it about **auto_t vehicle;
auto_t date;
auto_t tank;** that is better than **auto_t vehicle, date, tank;**?

Comment: `int main(void)` is ok, parameters just for input parameters in command line when invoke, it's my habit with out `void` if no parameters. And declare the struct as you did also ok as well. I changed just for testing.